# Apache .htaccess - Can't access a file while trying to protect?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I am attempting to lock a file out for me only (it's a log, and I don't want users to see it).

This is my .htpasswd:

```
foo:bar
```

And this is my .htaccess:

```
AuthUserFile /home/kapip/public_html/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "This is allowed for admin purposes only"

<Files "users.log">
  Require valid-user
</Files>
```

Even if I put in the correct password after the dialog, the dialog just flashes as if the request was sent, and then it pops up again. No matter what I put in, I can't see my file.

**Some Specs**

- I'm on shared hosting
- The .htpasswd, .htaccess, and log file are in the same directory
- Even if i change users.log to users.txt, it still doesn't work
- If I click "cancel" when it asks for credentials, it gives a 401 Response

Please help me! :(

Comment: Are you using cpanel or any other shared hosting panels? Although is not the best solution, you can use the password protect feature that will give you a hand with this kind of situations.

Comment: @Ken Check out [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions) for some advice on how to get more attention for an unanswered question.

Answer (score 2):

Did you run `htpasswd -c` on your password file? It's normally a hash and not a plaintext password. Take a look at the [htpasswd man page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htpasswd.html).

---

EDIT:

If you don't have shell access, you can create your htpasswd file using the [htpasswd generator](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) and the copy the file to your shared host. You should be able to use cPanel's FileManager.

One thing that I would suggest though: **You should NOT put your htpasswd file in your public_html directory, people will be able to access it via http://your-domain/.htpasswd which is VERY BAD**

Comment: I'm using CPanel - idk if I have terminal access.